# Configure scheduling to a program

Tags: centos, rhel, cgroups

The program "checking" should be autostart when the machine boot and should be start always with scheduling round robin with priority 27 in Rhel/Centos 7.

I can configure this scheduling with cgroups with a drop file but only to services, but in this case I need to do to a program.

How would you do?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a **cron** command for job scheduling ?

Refer to this link : [Automated Tasks | CentOS Project Documentation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time but this isn't my answer, I need to configure a program to autostart (no service) and to do that program always start with schedule round robin priority 27!. (crond is differente)